# Wrong NetStatusEvent for Flash multicast

Tags: actionscript-3, multicast, flash-media-server

I have created a simple multicast player using actinscript 3 which works fine and plays multicast stream well . Although when stream should fail . Or even if I stop Flash Media server it returns success  codes : "NetConnection.Connect.Success" ,"NetStream.Connect.Success" and "NetStream.Play.Start" . I cant detect  it when multicast stream fails in flash player. I need to switch to unicast stream if multicast fails and I cant detect a failure because of wrong status.

Why I am getting wrong status ?

Comment: Though the code is usually straight forward, it might be helpful to show your code. I've never had issues with getting incorrect status codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to figure this out from this link http://forums.adobe.com/message/4999537#4999537 . I now use NetStream.MulticastStream.Reset along with a timeout of 10 seconds .